# How do I create a timeline in my WordPress blog?

Tags: wordpress.com, widgets

I see some sites use a timeline graph using some Google tools. I am not able to get it in WordPress.

How do I get a timeline graph in a WordPress blog ?

Comment: Can you post a link to such a timeline, so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: like this one http://timeline.knightlab.com/ .  I am using wordpress.com online, not offline nor own domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress.com [doesn't allow](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#flash-and-other-embeds) for execution of arbiratry Javascript, neither does it allow iframes to be embedded in posts:

> If you are familiar with HTML, you’ll notice that codes such as **embed**, frame, **iframe**, form, input, object, textarea and others are missing from the above list. Those codes are not allowed on WordPress.com for security reasons.
>
> Users are not allowed to post JavaScript on WordPress.com blogs. JavaScript can be used for malicious purposes.

In other words, you can't use Timeline.js on WordPress.com

Comment: We implemented that exact timeline on a WordPress site: http://danielgordis.org/books/biography-of-menachem-begin/ (scroll down to about mid-page, and ignore the formatting, it needs to be fixed, I know). Why do you say it can't be done?

Comment: @MiriamSchwab OP's asking about wordpress.com, not hosted WordPress (ie WordPress on your own servers) which you have implemented